# C# LPT Name problem

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port, port, lpt

How can I send output to LPT in C#.
I use SerialPort class. I set port name to "LPT1" and I'm getting this error.

> The given port name does not start with COM/com or does not resolve to a valid serial port.
>   Parameter name: portName

What to do?

Comment: LPT ports aren't serial ports, they're parallel ports. You'll need to find a different class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use SerialPort to access a Parallel Port.  This will require P/Invoke to `inpout32.dll` to access.  For details, see [this tutorial](http://www.thaiio.com/prog-cgi/CshapeParallelPort.htm).